# Young adult science fiction novel set on Mars. Teenage romance between girl and guy with odd name

Tags: story-identification, mars

I read this book in high school, and it was fairly new, so published (approximately) between 2000 and 2004. From what I remember, there were two teenagers on Mars, a boy and a girl. The boy had an odd name and I think it started with a J. There was a romantic relationship between them. I know that's not much to go on but it's all I can remember...

Comment: Was it written between 2000 & 2004 or was that just when you read it. If the latter, when was it written (approximately). Can you descrive the cover? Anything else?

Comment: Hopefully more will come back to me but at the moment, that's all I remember. I think I read it in 2001 and it was fairly new so it must have been published close to then.

Comment: I think the cover was red and blue...

Comment: Was the girl named Nanoannie?

Comment: I can't remember her name.

Comment: Thank you all for your help - I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds similar to a series of young adult novels that I read years ago. The series is called *[Mars Diaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Diaries.)*.

It's a series of 10 short novels that were published between 2000 and 2002 by the author Sigmund Brouwer. The main character's name is Tyce, he's a teenager that grew up in an experimental community on Mars. A teenage girl named Ashley arrives on Mars early in the series, she is introduced in either the third or fourth book.

Comment: I don't think it was part of a series.